# SSL Connection error on Weblogic

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, ssl-certificate, weblogic12c

I am working on application. It is deployed on Weblogic and using the cluster.
After few hits on the application we are geeting SSL Connection Error.

On server Logs I saw this

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1639)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1607)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1776)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1080)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:884)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:758)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:664)
    at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine$5.run(JaSSLEngine.java:134)
    at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine.doAction(JaSSLEngine.java:732)
    at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine.unwrap(JaSSLEngine.java:132)
    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.unwrap(JSSEFilterImpl.java:585)
    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.unwrapAndHandleResults(JSSEFilterImpl.java:490)
    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.unwrapAndHandleResults(JSSEFilterImpl.java:457)
    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.isMessageComplete(JSSEFilterImpl.java:306)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.readReadySocketOnce(SocketMuxer.java:960)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.readReadySocket(SocketMuxer.java:897)
    at weblogic.socket.PosixSocketMuxer.processSockets(PosixSocketMuxer.java:130)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.run(SocketReaderRequest.java:29)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.execute(SocketReaderRequest.java:42)
    at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:147)
    at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:119)
```

Can any body please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug is related to coding problem in the application. Basically issue is with "Clone" a model object. Some one in the team have return a clone on Hibernate object which cloned all resources and cloned all child objects as well and the Object is so heavy and occupied lots of memory and by cloning it also claimed all resources and none were available to address next request.  Solved the issue by taking the clone, instead used filer option to get the required data and copied in simple POJO. I know we have many clone technique's but we do not want that because we just need some data from model.